# How To Accept Chrome Notifications Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, notifications, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-2022

[Notification Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ2Lg.png)

I have been all over stack overflow, but all the selenium stuff from 2018 is not working for me, can someone give me an update on how to change cookies/disable notifications/click accept.

None of the three things I'm doing right now are working

```
import selenium
import random
import keyboard
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())

option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)


driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)



# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 
})
```

I think I'm missing something with the webdriver/Chrome(service=service) bit or something. I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: You're setting the "option.add_experimental..." preference after you've created the driver.  Do that before.  Also be sure to include the options in your new driver call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the "option.add_experimental..." preference after you've created the driver. Do that before. Also be sure to include the options in your new driver call.

```
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
option=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=option)


driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Comment: An answer after a long time.